# excel chart mutiple data sets doesn't align properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to put 3 different data sets onto same chart, 2 of which use the same x-axis values (easy), and third that uses different (there is the problem). Best explained with a picture:

My data:
[image: data]

My chart:
[image: chart]

both `GUS IS` ant `wt` renders properly (there is additinal code that recomputes the `wt` values to fit on logaritmic axis, don't worry about that).

However, `IM` is wrong: it should be displayed from date `15.07.2016` to `04.08.2016` as indicated on the graph with the red line, but instead it's locked with the other data points.

If I hide the other data points, it will render correctly, so, haw can I render everything, and correctly?

I'm using MS Excel 2015 and generating the data via PHPExcel, if that is of any importance.

Comment: One solution is to use an overlay chart. That is where you have set the format for fill to no fill. Place it over the other chart. Depending on usage, may or may not get what you want.

Comment: A week or so ago I wrote a tutorial that covers this: [Multiple Time Series in an Excel Chart](http://peltiertech.com/multiple-time-series-excel-chart/)